# SUID issues with PHP + Apache

Tags: php, apache, exec, file-permissions

Ok, not sure what I am missing here. I'm trying to rename some files with a web accessible PHP script, without giving world write permissions on those files.  So I'm trying to use SUID on a PHP script (also tried a shell script).

There are three users which come into play, we'll call them APACHE, MATT, and BRIAN.
There is also a group called WEBDEV, which MATT and BRIAN are in.
There are two files which need to be renamed.  One is owned by MATT, the other by BRIAN. Both files group owner is WEBDEV.

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 MATT  WEBDEV 126179 Jun 20 12:03 g5g55.jpg
-rw-rw-r-- 1 BRIAN WEBDEV  41588 Jul 14  2006 g2g22.jpg
```

So my PHP script to be accessed in browser, called rename.php, runs as APACHE.  It cannot rename either of these files.  Naturally.  So the first thing I tried, which I didn't assume would work anyways, was to SUID the PHP script as MATT.

```
su MATT
chmod u+s /path/to/rename.php //also tried g+s
```

As I expected, no dice.  So I wrote a 2nd script, called move.php.

```
#!/usr/bin/php
//code to move file
```

Then SUID that script.

```
su MATT
chmod u+s /path/to/move.php //also tried g+s
```

Then from the original web accessed script, rename.php, I call:

```
shell_exec('/path/to/move.php');
```

I had higher hopes for this one, no dice again.  So I figure it's not working due to the PHP interpreter or Apache again.  Now I try the same thing, but with a new shell script called move.sh being exec'd from rename.php.

```
#!/bin/bash
//code to move file
```

And again it doesn't work.  If I exec the files move.php or move.sh from the shell as MATT, it works fine.  Not sure why this isn't working, or how I can make it work with SUID, rather than using sudo or setting up some sort of que that could be called from the properly privileged user's cron.  What is the best way to handle this? Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

Got it figured out for anyone who stumbles on this later. SUID doesn't work for shell scripts on my distro (or most for that matter).  Any subsequent commands called from a shell script will be run as the original user who launched it, not the user who set the SUID bit.  This applies for PHP and any exec calls you make too, you'd have to set the SUID bit on /usr/bin/php, which is obviously a very bad idea.  Or you can wrap your shell script in a C binary using a system call. I'm going to use SUDO.

Related info: 
https://serverfault.com/questions/282835/apache-mod-php-ignores-suid

Comment: This is not related to the PHP interprator. PHP is only accessing files as the user and it's rights the OS gives to PHP. Check your server config, learn how SUID and rights work before trying three times the same with only changing names. Check under which user the script is actually executed and then reflect the file permissions accordingly: `echo shell_exec('whoami');`.

Comment: @hakre The difference was not merely renaming the files.  They were all invoked differently. Albeit all stemming from apache + mod_php which very well could be the problem.  whoami reports the user running the script regardless of the SUID bit being set. I don't want to just allow  apache to write to these files, I want that controlled and only doable with very specific parameters being enforced.

Answer (score 0):

Have all 3 users belong in the group WEBDEV, and then change all files to be owned by APACHE, group WEBDEV:

```
// From your project topmost directory:
chown -R APACHE:WEBDEV .
```

Give group read write access to this directory, and everything inside of it (-R = recursive)

```
chmod -R g+rw .
```

As you can see, 'nux permission schemes are very flexible and take a little bit of head-banging to get used to. [Many more juicy examples here](http://www.dartmouth.edu/~rc/help/faq/permissions.html).

Comment: I don't want to give apache all out write access to the files.  Every file on the site is part of the webdev group, I might as well run apache as root at that point, or chmod 777 the entire webroot.  I'm trying to give apache the ability to write to these files, but only from a single controlled script.